MariaDB stopped working after upgrading Debian buster to bookworm
Have a Debian server VM running on ESXI host. i just upgraded it from Debian buster to bookworm but after the upgrade MariaDB service will not start. Have tried multiple times but not getting it to work.
MariaDB version: 11.4.3
When i start the MariaDB prosess i get this error in the syslog
systemd[1]: Starting mariadb.service - MariaDB 11.4.3 database server...
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=4/ILL
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: failed with result 'signal'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start mariadb.service - MariaDB 11.4.3 database server.
kernel: [ 985.656570] traps: mariadbd[14149] trap invalid opcode ip:55a337eab5c2 sp:7ffe719fb38 error:0 in mariadbd[55a337512000+a5c000]

More info:
apt-cache policy
Package files:
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
release a=now
500 https://mirror.group.one/mariadb/repo/11.4/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages 
release o=MariaDB, n=bookworm, 1=MariaDB, c=main, b=amd64
origin mirror.group.one
500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages
release v=12-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bookworm-updates,1=Debian,c=main,b=amd64 
origin deb.debian.org
500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages
release v=12,0=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bookworm-security,1=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64 
origin security.debian.org
500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
release v=12.7,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bookworm,1=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
origin deb.debian.org
Pinned packages:


ii libdbd-mariadb-perl  1.22-1+b1   amd64   Perl5 database interface to the MariaDB/MySQL databases
ii libmariadb3:amd64    1:11.4.3+maria~deb12    amd64   MariaDB database client library
ii mariadb-backup   1:11.4.3+maria~deb12    amd64   Backup tool for MariaDB server
ii mariadb-client   1:11.4.3+maria~deb12    amd64   MariaDB database client binaries
rc mariadb-client-10.5  1:10.5.21+maria~deb11   amd64   MariaDB database client binaries
ii mariadb-client-compat    1:11.4.3+maria~deb12    all MySQL compatibility links to mariadb-client binaries/scripts.
ii mariadb-client-core  1:11.4.3+maria~deb12    amd64   MariaDB database core client binaries
ii mariadb-common   1:11.4.3+maria~deb12    all MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
iF mariadb-server   1:11.4.3+maria~deb12    amd64   MariaDB database server binaries
rc mariadb-server-10.5  1:10.5.21+maria~deb11   amd64   MariaDB database server binaries
iU mariadb-server-compat    1:11.4.3+maria~deb12    all MySQL compatibility links to mariadb-server binaries/scripts.
ii mariadb-server-core  1:11.4.3+maria~deb12    amd64   MariaDB database core server files


Did you install Mariadb from somewhere other than the debian repo? Have you reinstalled Mariadb from the same source since upgrading debian?

Installed it from the MariaDB repo for Debian, and have allways used that. Tried reinstalling it from another server also. https://mariadb.org/download/?t=repo-config&d=Debian+12+%22Bookworm%22&v=11.4&r_m=dotsrc

Add the output of apt-cache policy and dpkg-query -l | grep mariadb to the question. Also, are the databases important? If so, do you have backups?

@NasirRiley have updated original post with that. I have backups of the database and i have a snapshot of the server that before upgrading the server, so i have not lost anything, just want the server upgraded, and i was hoping not to rebuild the server

While troubleshooting can be done, it sometimes easier and more viable to uninstall and reinstall and import backups. The fact that you have them allows that in this case. By default, the logs for mariadb go to /var/log/mysql/error.log and /var/log/mysql/mysql.log unless you have modified the conf file to have them go elsewhere. Run tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log while starting the mariadb daemon and add the output to the question. If you have the logs set to go elsewhere, then add the tail -f of that log file while starting the daemon.
